# Embedded Tomcat does not start

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to run a web application on an embedded instance of Tomcat. So I placed it on a directory webapps and I run the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String currentDir = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();       
    String appBase = currentDir + File.separatorChar + "webapps";  
    System.out.println(appBase);
    Integer port = 4040;
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(port);
    tomcat.setBaseDir(".");

    tomcat.addWebapp("/myTools.war", appBase);
    tomcat.setHostname("localhost");
    tomcat.start();

    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(999999999);
    }
}
```

The Tomcat instance seems to start (although I get some warnings of the type "Could not get url for /javax/servlet...", but I read this is normal). However when I connect to localhost:4040 or localhost:4040/myTools I see just a blank page (or a Tomcat warning that the address does not exist). I also tried to expand the war into a directory and use

```
tomcat.addWebapp("/myTools", appBase);
```

but nothing changed. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the (horrifying) endless while slope at the end and replace it with:

```
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

Comment: yes that's the way I did it in the beginning, I added the endless while in one of the many attempts to make it work! But I agree it's horrible.